# ウイルス対策ソフトの公開サーバ構築について

Tags: windows, サーバー管理

表題の件について質問させていただきたいのですが、そもそも私の基礎知識自体が稚拙すぎるためあっちこっちに飛ぶような文章になってしまうであろうことを、どうかご容赦ください。

Windows Serverに関する質問なのですが、企業のクライアントPCにはシマンテックやウイルスバスターといった様々なウイルス対策ソフトがインストールされていると思います（個人PCにおいてもですが）。

そこで、例えば各クライアントPCに対し、

1. 特定のソフトの一括インストールをサーバ側で統括して行うなどということは可能でしょうか。
2. また、1の質問での答えが仮にNOである場合、では定期的にセキュリティソフトの更新作業等をサーバ側でコントロールすることは可能なのでしょうか。
3. 「公開サーバ」という言葉の意味がまず私にはわかっていないのですが、例えばWSUSのように、複数のクライアントPCが本来であれば個別に行うような一連の作業を、一手に引き受けるものという認識で合っていますか。
4. 「ウイルス対策／セキュリティ対策ソフトの公開サーバ構築」このキーワードから、だいたいどういったことを行うサーバを立てるのか、詳細は除いて少しだけ具体的なイメージをお持ちになられる有識者の方がいらっしゃいましたら、そのイメージだけでも何となくご教授くださいますと幸いです。

現在の私は、とりあえず1台にサーバにウイルス対策ソフトを入れました…そしてここから「公開サーバ」というゴールに向かうための道筋が右も左もわかっていない状態でございます。

何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「公開サーバ」なる文言の対する合意が読者とあなたの間にないと、我々読者が自分の解釈で何を書いてもあなたの認識とはすれ違うっつか。オイラの認識では WSUS は公開サーバとは呼べない・呼ばないです。その辺のすり合わせが先かと。

Comment: 単に「サーバ」だけだと範囲が広すぎるので、どんな役割のサーバなのかをまず絞り込む必要があると思います (webサーバ、メールサーバ、ファイルサーバ etc...)。 / また、「公開」と付けるのは "インターネット上に" といった意味合いになる気がするので、本文に出てくるWSUSなどの「閉じた環境」で使うサーバとは話が繋がらない印象です。 / ヘルプの [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) も参考にしながら、一度質問文を見直してもらえればと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさにおっしゃられる通りだと思います。もう少し具体的なシステム要件を把握します。失礼いたしました。